# Last Dictionary<Key Value> is not added to the List from a CSV import in Unity

Tags: css, list, csv, dictionary, unity-game-engine

So i try to read a CSV script modular in Unity. Everything works nearly fine only the last Key Value is not added to the list although it exists in the Dictionary.

```
    string[] data = fileString.Split(new string[] {";", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    Debug.Log(data.Length);
    int rows = data.Length / columns - 1;

    List<string> kartenvariablen = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i<= columns; i++)
    {
         kartenvariablen.Add(data[i]);                
    }
    Debug.Log(kartenvariablen.Count);
    Debug.Log(kartenvariablen[9]);

    List<Dictionary<string, string>>  allCards = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    for(int i=0; i< rows; i++)       
    { 
        Dictionary<string, string> singleCard = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        for(int n= 0; n <= columns; n++)
        {
            singleCard.Add(kartenvariablen[n], data[columns+1+n+(i*(columns+1))]);     
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> s in singleCard)
        {
            Debug.Log(s);   //here it returns Alignment TopLeft
        }
        allCards.Add(singleCard);
       
    }
    Debug.Log(allCards[2]["PrefabName"]); //returns test3 
    Debug.Log(allCards[2]["Alignment"]); //returns KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'Alignment' was not present in the dictionary.
```

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) (at <6073cf49ed704e958b8a66d540dea948>:0)
CSVTemplateReader.ReadCSV () (at Assets/Scripts/CSVTemplateReader.cs:106)
CSVTemplateReader.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/CSVTemplateReader.cs:19)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwqOD.png)

Comment: How many rows does your code think it’s doing. Are you sure it’s not finding empty rows?

Comment: The code has in this case 3 rows and the variable rows has the value = 2.
If i try to access allCards[0][Alignment] throws the same error.

Comment: `columns+1+n+(i*(columns+1))` doesn’t look right.  As if you had 8 columns. You would say have value n=7but 8+1+7+(2*7)=30 but you only have 24 data entries

Answer (score 0):

Probably either:

```
int rows = data.Length / columns;
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i <= rows; i++)
```

is required in your case

Comment: Unluckily this only throws an Index out of Bounds Error and doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: I would refactor the code so i split data just by '\n', get the lines count and then in for loop split each line by ';'. Splitting by both '\n' and ';' at same time and dividing by expected column count sounds like a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the code. The logic behind was completely fine.
The problem was it didnt saved the Alignment Key with "Alignment", but he saved it as "Alignment\r".
So i refactored the code at the beginning with:
string[] data = fileString.Split(new string[] {";", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
And now it works completely fine. Thanks for all the answers and the help!